# Are vault-writes synchronous or asynchronous in Corda

Tags: corda

I have written a flow which creates a transaction that outputs a new state (`TransactionBuilder.signInitialTransaction`), and then passes it to `FinalityFlow` to notarize/record/broadcast it. My client-application is starting this flow over RPC with `CordaRPCOps.startFlowDynamic` and waits for the returned `CordaFuture`s `getOrThrow()`. This is rather slow, since `FinalityFlow` only returns once it has delivered the transaction to all other parties/nodes (in fact, if a remote-node is down it seems to never return).

I figured I can speed things up by letting my application only wait for `FinalityFlow` to have completed `notarizeAndRecord()`, as I should then have the tx/states in my nodes vault and I can safely assume that other nodes will eventually have this tx delivered and accept it. I implemented this using `ProgressTracker`, waiting only until `FinalityFlow` sets `currentStep` to `BROADCASTING`.

However, what I'm observing is that if I query the vault (using `CordaRPCOps.vaultQueryByCriteria`) for the new state very shortly after `notarizeAndRecord` has returned, I *sometimes* do not yet get it returned. Is this a bug or rather some deliberate asynchronous behavior where the database is not immediately written to ?

To work around this I then tried to synchronize with the vault inside my flow, in order to update the progressTracker only after the tx/state was actually written to the vault:

```
val stx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(tx)
serviceHub.vaultService.rawUpdates.subscribe {
    logger.info("receiving update $it")
    if(it.produced.any { it.ref.txhash == stx.id }) {
        progressTracker.currentStep = RECORDED
    }
}
subFlow(FinalityFlow(stx))
```

I can see the update in the node-logs, yet a subsequent vault-query by the RPC-Client (which also shows in the node-logs, *after* the update) for that very state still does not return anything if executed immediately afterwards...

I am running Corda v2.0.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether vault writes are synchronous.

However, you can side-step this issue by creating an observable on the vault so that you are notified when the new state is recorded. Here's an example where we update a state using its linear ID, then wait for vault updates matching that linear ID:

```
proxy.startFlowDynamic(UpdateState::class.java, stateLinearId)
val queryCriteria = QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(linearId = listOf(stateLinearId))
val (snapsnot, updates) = proxy.vaultTrackBy<MyLinearState>(queryCriteria)

updates.toBlocking().subscribe { update ->
    val newVaultState = update.produced.single()
    // Perform action here.
}
```